# Retrieve list items dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have a list with one lookup field and a large amount of other custom columns. I need to retrieve all the fields but only my custom columns without to specifiy them becouse the solution needs to be dynamic.

I use REST api for SP 2013 and this is my url so far:

```
url + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('myListTitle')/items/?$select=process/Title&$expand=process/Title
```

Is their any solution so i dont need to specify all my columns in `$select` query?

Comment: Can you be more clear how you want the $select be dynamic?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to retrive all my custom columns without to specify them?

Comment: You can. But you will miss lookup column's info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with this approach:

1. Use [Field Colleciton Endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldCollectionEndpoint) to retrieve all the fields of your list. You can filter fields by checking their READONLY and HIDDEN properties. If they are true, probably they are system fields.
2. On success, generate your $select string dynamically on the base of the result and then execute the get call.

Comment: To expand on this, you can use the `FromBaseType` property to find 'custom' fields that are not part of a content type with an endpoint like `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Children')/fields?$filter=((FromBaseType eq false) and (Hidden eq false)) or (StaticName eq 'Title')` if you do have them inheriting from a content type you can look for that content type in the field item

Comment: It worked! Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use `$expand` without `$select`. In the $select, it is needed to specify all the columns you are need. I have tried to get items from following `URL` without `$select`.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items?$expand=LooKUp/Title
```

**Error:**

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The query to field 'LooKUp' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains LooKUp."
        }
    }
}
```

Following end-point should give you all custom columns without expanding lookups

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items
```

Above end-point will give you lookup column's `ID`. If you need any information from this lookup column, the you have to make an another GET with this `ID`. Following end-point can be used for getting lookup column's info.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')/GetItemById('lookup column id')
```